# Is there a shorter way to equal height of blocks using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Where is the shortest way?

```
var height=0;
$('.el').each(function(){
height<$(this).height()?height=$(this).height():height=height
}).height(height);
```

If it exists, of course.

**EDIT:**
Nice, thanks gyus!

```
var h=0;
$('.el').each(function(){
    h=Math.max(h,$(this).height());
}).height(h);
```

Comment: I'd say there wasn't one really, but someone *may* prove me wrong :)

Comment: Looks like I proved myself wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly *shorter*, but *cleaner* and *faster* I guess:

```
$(".el").height(Math.max.apply(null, $(".el").map(function () {
    return $(this).height();
}).get()));
```

Comment: Check my edit, don't even need a variable now it's changed *automagically* :)

Comment: Nice, but complicated to understand ;)

Comment: You think so? I think your conditional is harder personally :P

Answer (score 0):

Appending `.height(height);` onto your method will only update the height of elements after a new max is found.
You want to loop back through the elements and change them to the new found max height afterwards.
Also, use Math.max for the compares.

4 less characters than yours, and it updates all elements.

```
var h=0;
$('.el').each(function(){h=Math.max(h,$(this).height());});
$('.el').each(function(){$(this).height(h);});
```

Comment: Your version is shorter, but there is cleaner one in my edit.

Comment: @yaponyal That's basically exactly what I had.. Changed height to h, used Math.max instead... gg.